# Special characters are not displayed in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an xml file containing words with special characters.
For example:

```
<string name="test_text">"test¹, test², test⁶, test⁷ "</string>
```

When I use the string via the instruction:

```
((TextView) view.finViewdById(R.id.test)).setText(R.string.test_text);
```

the output will be:

> test¹, test², test, test

I can not display the special characters:⁶, ⁷.

Can someone help me fix the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tested it using two options:

```
Log.d("TEST", getString(R.string.test_text));
Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.test_text), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

In the Toast it indeed appears as `test¹, test², test, test`, while in Logcat string appears correctly - `test¹, test², test⁶, test⁷` - so it looks like everything is fine with the way you define your string resource.

My guess is that default font, used for UI, does not provide these characters (`⁶` and `⁷`). You can try using your own font from assets, making sure it has support for the required characters

Comment: In fact I realized that it is a font problem. Can you recommend some font that makes my case? Those present in Typeface are not working properly.

Comment: It's pretty hard to predict which font will suit your needs. Perhaps you can give `DejaVuSans.ttf` a try. Just add it to `assets` folder of your project and use it like `tv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "DejaVuSans.ttf"));`, where `tv` is your TextView.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.test)).setText(getString(R.string.test_text, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: This does not seem right: `getString (int resId, Object... formatArgs)` ([specification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)) : `"UTF-8"` will be treated as format argument, not encoding

Comment: just checked in my device.. and it is working fine. May be I am wrong in some aspects... checking again

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the header on the xml file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

If the problem is still happen or you need to ensure everything show correctly. You can save the String as a utf8 encoded code and parse it after read it out. Like what swing window builder do if you entering special character in Swing GUI window builder.